# How to use for_each loop terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I'm trying to create aws vpc connection module. And can not figure out how to use for_each loop (like map, set of stings) for my var.env. For each var.env == "stage" use one peer-id, for each var.env != "stage" use another peer-id.
Here is my variables and main files:

variables.tf

```
variable "peer-id" {
  type = string
}

variable "env" {
  type = string
}
```

main.tf

```
resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter" "remote" {
  vpc_peering_connection_id = var.peer-id
  auto_accept               = true
  
  tags = {
    Name = "stage"
  }
  
  lifecycle {ignore_changes = [tags]}
}

resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_options" "accepter" {
  for_each = toset(["stage"])
  vpc_peering_connection_id = "var.peer-id"

  accepter {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }
  
  requester {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }

  depends_on = [aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter.remote]
}

resource "aws_vpc_peering_connection_options" "accepter-external" {
  count = var.env != "dev" ? 1 : 0
  vpc_peering_connection_id = var.peer-id

  accepter {
    allow_remote_vpc_dns_resolution = true
  }

  depends_on = [aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter.remote]
}

data "aws_route_tables" "private" {
  count = var.env != "dev" ? 1 : 0
  vpc_id = aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter.remote.vpc_id

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Tier"
    values = ["Private"]
  }
}

data "aws_route_tables" "private_dev" {
  count = var.env == "dev" ? 1 : 0

  vpc_id = aws_vpc_peering_connection_accepter.remote.peer_vpc_id

  filter {
    name   = "tag:Tier"
    values = ["Private"]
  }
}

resource "aws_route" "requster_route" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_route_tables.private.ids)
  route_table_id            = data.aws_route_tables.private.0.ids
  destination_cidr_block    = "192.168.0.0/16"
  vpc_peering_connection_id = var.peer-id

  depends_on = [data.aws_route_tables.private]
}

resource "aws_route" "requster_route_dev" {
  for_each = toset(data.aws_route_tables.private.ids)
  route_table_id            = data.aws_route_tables.private_dev.0.ids
  destination_cidr_block    = "192.168.0.0/16"
  vpc_peering_connection_id = var.peer-id
  depends_on = [data.aws_route_tables.private_dev]
}
```

Also tried with set of strings, there are no errors but i don't think that i do it correctly.

```
Error: Missing resource instance key
    │ 
    │   on main.tf line 128, in resource "aws_route" "requster_route":
    │  128:   for_each = toset(data.aws_route_tables.private.ids)
    │ 
    │ Because data.aws_route_tables.private has "count" set, its attributes must be accessed on     specific instances.
    │ 
    │ For example, to correlate with indices of a referring resource, use:
    │     data.aws_route_tables.private[count.index]
```

Comment: It should be `toset(data.aws_route_tables.private[0].ids)`, but also make sure that the code doesn't throw an error if the `var.env != "dev"`.

Comment: @markoE Error: Invalid for_each argument. on main.tf line 128, in resource "aws_route" "requster_route":
│  128:   for_each = toset(data.aws_route_tables.private[0].ids)
│     ├────────────────
│     │ data.aws_route_tables.private[0].ids is a list of string, known only after apply

Comment: Try moving it to a local variable, then running plan prior to running apply.